# Database changes are not pushing to server

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a winforms application, that is using the datasource and dataset controls from the IDE

This is the code block i am using

```
        dsParcelBatch.BC_cpo_PARCELRow pr = dsParcelBatch.BC_cpo_PARCEL.FindByISN(int.Parse(activeParcelID));
    pr.BeginEdit();
    pr.NODE_ISN = 6;
    pr.EndEdit();       
    pr.AcceptChanges();

    dsParcelBatch.AcceptChanges();
```

I can read the correct row in line 1, and it is populating the PR row with the correct values,
i call the beginedit, and the dsParcelBatch has not updated.

I change the value of the NODE_ISN to the new value, and it sticks

I close the edit, and accept the changes in the row.
I can look into the datasource (dsParcelBatch) and the changes are in there - YEA!

I call the dsParcelBatch, and the changed value is changed....

but when i view the database, the value is back to the original value (5)

What am i missing something?

Comment: hello, are you sur that your field activeParcelID is not a primary key? try to change another field and verify that it changes on database

Comment: activeParcelID is the primary key....   but again, the values are begin saved in the dataset in memory, and i can view them, they are just not being written to the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before calling AcceptChanges you need to use a [DataAdapter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbdataadapter.aspx) to [Update](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/at8a576f.aspx) the database.

AcceptChanges only changes the state of the rows in the DataTable, not in the database.

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.acceptchanges):

> When AcceptChanges is called, any DataRow object still in edit mode
>   successfully ends its edits. The DataRowState also changes: all Added
>   and Modified rows become Unchanged, and Deleted rows are removed.

Comment: Where would I place this "dataadapter" in the code from above?  I have the dataset and datarow, both are showing the correct values when i inspect them in the IDE.   thanks for the reply

Comment: Just before the AcceptChanges call. Look at the example I linked to. Note that you will have to use the correct version SqlDataAdapter or OleDBDataAdapter or ...